# Using regex to parse a delimited array in bash

Tags: regex, bash, svg, grep, pcre

I have a file that contains the following line:

`<polyline id="graph" points="0,287 100,470 200,509 300,459 400,471"/>`

And I need to extract the following values:

`287 470 509 459 471`

I am currently using this code:

`grep -oP '(?<=points=").*(?="/>)' "file.svg" | grep -oP '(?<=,)[[:digit:]]*'`

I want to do it with a single `grep`, I tried using `(?:)`, with no success. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sed solution can be like

```
$ sed -r '/points=/ s/[^,]+,?([0-9]*)/\1 /g' input
287 470 509 459 471
```

OR

for much better handling

```
$ sed -r '/points=/ s/.*points=("[^"]+").*/\1/g; s/[^,]+,?([0-9]*)/\1 /g' input
287 470 509 459 471
```

Comment: Hmm if line is like this: `<polyline foo="1,2,3,4" id="graph" points="0,287 100,470 200,509 300,459 400,471"/>` then above sed produces: `2 ,4 287 470 509 459 471`

Comment: @anubhava I have added to include that as well. Hope there wont be much more loopholes left ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're just parsing a single line like that, you might get away with using `XML::Simple`, like this:

```
perl -MXML::Simple -lwe'$x = XMLin(<>); print $x->{points};' file.svg
```

With your line, this gives me the following output:

```
0,287 100,470 200,509 300,459 400,471
```

The entire structure in `$x` parsed from that line looks like this when printed with `Data::Dumper`:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'points' => '0,287 100,470 200,509 300,459 400,471',
          'id' => 'graph'
        };
```

Note that you may need to pre-process your input, if it is more complex than you indicated in your question.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is no `perl` on that platform. I tagged it because of the `-P` switch...

Answer (score 1):

It's XML, so parse as XML.

```
use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parse ( '<polyline id="graph" points="0,287 100,470 200,509 300,459 400,471"/>' );
print $twig ->  root -> {'att'} -> {'points'};
```

Although - you might need something slightly different if you want to parse it out of a svg file - but you can then use `$twig -> parsefile`.

Simplifies as a one liner:

```
perl -MXML::Twig -e 'print XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ("test.xml" ) -> root -> first_child("polyline") -> {"att"}{"points"};'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use gnu-awk:

```
awk -v RS='points="[^"]+"' 'RT{s=RT; gsub(/[^[:digit:], ]|[[:digit:]]+,/, "", s); 
   print s}' file
287 470 509 459 471
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F\" '/points/ {gsub(/[0-9]+,/,"",$4);print $4}' file
287 470 509 459 471
```

If position on the line do change, do:

```
awk -F"points=" 'NF==2{gsub(/[0-9]+,|[^0-9 ]/,"",$2);print $2}' file
287 470 509 459 471
```